# How to pass dynamic data to angular directives

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7 in my application. i have added one directive to show the tooltip.
Please see the below example link
[Sample example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-santhosh-tooltip?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip.directive.ts)
here i need to pass  directive placement dynamically.
kindly let me know how to do it.

I am not supposed to use ngOnchanges(-) method.

Comment: Why u cant use ngOnChanges?

Comment: it is very costly in terms of memory, performance..

Comment: ngOnChanges runs anyway. Its part of the angular lifecycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your property in `[]` and your good to go.
e.g.:

```
[tooltip]="item.Name"
```

Now the tooltip changes then you `item.Name` changes

Comment: super , actually i forgot to use property binding